# Progress Error: Invalid query with CONTAINS

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I'm getting the error "Invalid query with CONTAINS" in one of our application server logs. This service was not experiencing this error yesterday and I'm not aware of anything in our code that might have changed.

Can anyone give any insight into what might be causing this error outside of our code?

Comment: Sorry, off-topic, but I was curious since your bio says you're in Madison... if you don't mind me asking, what company in Madison uses Progress?

Comment: @AbeVoelker There are many companies in Madison that use Progress. The City of Madison also has extensive use of Progress in their systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) CONTAINS operator uses word indexes. Check if index is setup correctly for the error query.

2) If a word index is defined on a CHARACTER field that is large, you might consider increase the value of the Stash Area (–stsh) startup parameter.

3) You can also try to rebuild your indexes useing the PROUTIL utility with the IDXBUILD or IDXFIX qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an error generated by Progress ABL or by your logic? Do you have a Progress Error number on that?

Did you change the encoding of your database? The CONTAINS operator relies on the word break rules and if you change the encoding of the database (for example to UTF-8 where there are no word break rules defined) you might experience the CONTAINS operator not working anymore without you having changed anything in the code. If that's the case you must generate the word break rules. But that is just a guess.